# Using layoutcomplete with Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope to place some grid elements which is working fine. Now I need to run some code on layoutcomplete so I have added the event and end up with the following code.

```
var $container = $('.iso');
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        ...
    });

    $container.isotope('on', 'layoutComplete',
        function (isoInstance, laidOutItems) {
            ...
        }
    );
});
```

This all works fine except that layoutcomplete is not executed on page load which is of course beacuse the event is added after init. I have then tried setting isInitLayout: false but is then having problem what to do next - I would expect that I could use .arrange() but with no luck.

Anybody who can figure out how I get layoutComplete to execute on page load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was pulling my hair off too because of isotope for a long time. But as much as I experienced the 2.0.1 version of it finally we got a stable plugin.

You can use the code below to layout/relayout your isotope:

```
$container.isotope('layout');
```

I recommend you to use `isInitLayout: false`.

Also keep in mind this, if your containers size changes and your isotope is responsive then your layoutComplete gets fired everytime when it happens. So, you may need to use `once` instead of `on`.

```
var $container = $('.iso');
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
       isInitLayout: false
    });

    $container.isotope('on', 'layoutComplete',
        function (isoInstance, laidOutItems) {
            ...
        }
    );

    $container.isotope('layout');
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: completely forgot this question - you are right and more or less I ended up doing the exact same thing as you.

Comment: unfortunately, the above doesn't work with the latest version